# Operands in verilog

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to implement a PID controller using Verilog, but I faced some problems in the coding.

I try to set the position as a `parameter` like shown in the screens shot:

[image]

but, I faced an error which I am not aware of:

[image]

Error1:-

```
Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at Verilog1.v(16) near text: "[";  expecting an operand. Check for and fix any syntax errors that appear immediately before or at the specified keyword. The Intel FPGA Knowledge Database contains many articles with specific details on how to resolve this error. Visit the Knowledge Database at https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/search.html and search for this specific error message number.
```

Error2:-

```
Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at Verilog1.v(34) near text: "[";  expecting "@", or an operand. Check for and fix any syntax errors that appear immediately before or at the specified keyword. The Intel FPGA Knowledge Database contains many articles with specific details on how to resolve this error. Visit the Knowledge Database at https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/search.html and search for this specific error message number.
```

I also tried the like `integer position=  [0*IRL+1000*CIR+2000*IRR];`, but still, I face the same problem.  How do I fix this syntax error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After compiling, parameter values can only be read; not modified. They are runtime constants.   An `integer` type can only be assigned within an procedural block. You can give it an initial value at declarations, but it will not auto update. So you want a procedure assignment or a net type with continuous assignment.

Square brackets (`[]`) are used for indexing an array or slice of a vector. They cannot be used like parentheses (`()`) or curly brackets (`{}`). In your case non are needed.

Change:

```
integer position=  [0*IRL+1000*CIR+2000*IRR];
```

To:

```
wire [31:0] position=  0*IRL+1000*CIR+2000*IRR;
```

Or:

```
wire [31:0] position;
assign position=  0*IRL+1000*CIR+2000*IRR;
```

Or:

```
integer position;
always @* begin
  position=  0*IRL+1000*CIR+2000*IRR;
end
```

---

Also change:

```
Proportional<= [position/IRL+CIR+IRR]-1000;
```

To:

```
Proportional<= (position/IRL+CIR+IRR)-1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `IRL`, `CIR` and `IRR` are declared as constant type (like `parameter`), then you should remove the square brackets:

```
parameter position = 0*IRL+1000*CIR+2000*IRR;
```

Comment: @UnparedElectron: If you mean `input` port, then that is illegal syntax.  As I said, you must use constants, not variables.